# How to disable blue notification badges in VS Code's Activity Bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't stand these things, any way to turn them off?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To disable the Git badge, you can add this to your `settings.json`:

```json
"git.countBadge": "off"
```

I could not find an equivalent setting for the unsaved file counter. However, as a workaround, enabling auto-save with a short delay also disables that badge:

```json
"files.autoSave": "afterDelay"
```

Comment: If I set "git.countBadge": "off", I see flickering of blue badge on source control's icon after each save of files. Autosave do it frequently, so it is very annoying. I end up hiding it.

Comment: I have found the solution for my problem: "git.showProgress": true 
(from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57115288/meaning-of-clock-icon-in-vs-code-source-control )

Answer (score 4):

There  is an ability to disable badges for Activity Bar Views in the Stable Build v1.74 now.

In the context menu for each icon - but NOT for Accounts - is a toggle `Hide Badge` or `Show Badge`.

[image: toggle activity bar badges]

- from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/823fe5dfc85e89ba98b545ff5b746328562a5dbc

I think settings and/or commands may be coming to toggle these badges on or off but aren't in the Insiders Build yet.

Comment: Confirmed this works, thanks! This is a better answer than the accepted one atm

Comment: Work has been commited to make this hiding of badges persist across reloads/restarts of vscode, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74855481/836330.

Answer (score 2):

If you never actually use the Source Control tab, you can right-click and hide it entirely.

That should at least get rid of the distracting flicker that happens a few seconds after every save.

Comment: I ended up getting rid of all the tabs entirely—and use hot keys to switch between things. Distraction free workspace really is 100% vital to deep work, I have no idea why people thought it'd be good to throw icons and notifications everywhere.

Comment: @Mirror318 You would enjoy the Zen Mode of VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

```json
"git.showProgress": false,
"git.countBadge": "off",
"scm.countBadge": "off",
```

Comment: While these settings may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* they answer the question and where to put them improves its long-term value.