# Meaning of clock icon in VS Code source control

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

What does it mean when a blue clock icon is displayed over the VS Code source control icon? When I run the git status command, I get the message: "nothing to commit, working tree clean." I checked the VS Studio documentation, but I couldn't find anything on this topic.

[image]

Comment: No help from the docs https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol as far as I can tell

Comment: What's the tooltip say when you hover over it?  You could also poke into the command palette and "Toggle Developer Tools" to maybe see the resource name or classes and see if that's descriptive

Comment: When I hover over the clock icon,the tooltip says "Source Control (Ctrl+Shift+G)".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- The clock icon is the progress marker, or 'VSCode is still working on
  this...' marker.
- The designer's expectation is that this would be a
  momentary notification, not a long one.
- When you open a new directory for
  the first time, but do not have a `.gitignore` set up, this means it
  wants to slurp your `node_modules` or directory of intermediate
  object files and such.  This takes a long time, or forever if it
  crashes and restarts, and so you keep seeing the icon.
- Add a `.gitignore` file.
- Restart VS Code if necessary.  If you still have trouble, consider sacrificing a live chicken over the CPU (reports say a Rhode Island Red works, but YMMV).

Comment: live chicken _under_ the CPU worked for me, less impact on keyboard

Answer (score 12):

The clock is the "Progress Badge" which is visible while VS Code is getting repository info and status:

[image: VS Code Git Progress Badge]

You can disable it in settings:

```js
{ 
  // controls whether git actions should show progress
  "git.showProgress": true
}
```

Comment: Thank you for additionally including how to disable this little git progress timer icon in vscode. It had always distracted me, and having it disabled lets me focus back on the tasks at hand. :)

Answer (score 3):

When you make a change to a file and then save, the clock icon appears for a second and then disappear. I think it reads the changes you did, and add the newly changed file under the source control, so if you click on that file, you can see the difference between the old and the new version. I believe, it compares the differences when you make any change to show you the correct status beside each file, like Modified, added, etc..

Comment: The clock icon finally disappeared after I restarted VS Code a couple of times. This seems to be a bug in VS Code, since the icon should have disappeared earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The way I fixed this was to rename my existing git project and clone a new copy from GitHub. Then I used a compare utility (WinMerge in my case) to compare old broken project vs new cloned project. I moved changes from old to new slowly and updated GitHub with commits & pushes frequently.

At one point, I moved over a recently created temp directory tree with thousands of files and the new project became borked just like the old. As I didn't want the temp files in git anyway, I updated my .gitignore files properly and the problem was resolved.

In my case, the problem was *way* too many untracked files.