# How do you hide the "updates available" badge for VSCode extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode has a blue badge on the Extensions tab showing how many extensions updates are available. This thing lights up a couple times per day and it's right beside the badge that tells me if I have uncommitted Git changes. This makes it super distracting because it's right beside a badge that really matters. I care about Git. I definitely do NOT care if every single extension is 100% up to date.

How do I permanently turn off the badges on the Extensions tab?

Edit: I'm aware that you can right-click and "Hide badge", but this only gets applied to one vscode window and the badges re-appear as soon as you restart that window.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42042369/how-to-disable-blue-notification-badges-on-vs-code/74524986#74524986  Just right-click on the icon and select `Hide Badge`

Comment: Thanks @Mark, I forgot to mention that and have edited my posting.

I'm looking for a permanent way to disable badges. Having to repeatedly tell vsocde to `Hide Badge` is almost as annoying as the badge itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A commit has just been added to vscode (closing the issue cited below) to enable the persistence of hiding those view badges, see [Ensure badge state is persisted in activity bar cache](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/173715).  Shouldbe in the next Insiders Build and Stable v1.76 early March 2023.

---

As you noted in the comment, right-clicking and `Hide Badge` (see [How to disable blue notification badges on VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42042369/how-to-disable-blue-notification-badges-on-vs-code/74524986#74524986)) is not remembered between reloads of vscode.

I don't think there is a way to do that currently, so upvote the github issue
[Persist state of numbered-badges hiddenness](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/168939)

Comment: Nice, I hadn't found that when I was searching about extensions badges on github. Thanks for the link, I just upvoted that issue.